# Triggering an 'error' type eventlistener on a HTTPRequest?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a HTTPRequest that I use to send the below:

```
  cw.xhr.load({
  "method": "GET",
  "rdata": dataJSON,
  "url": "php/entries.php",
  "responce": {
    "load": formatResults,
    "error": errorLoading
  }
```

-- cw.xhr is my XHR request that I use to send the above object.
In the HTTPRequest, I have added an eventlistner on the "load" and the "error"

This works fine and if I echo anything from the entries.php, then it will trigger the 'formatResults' JS function and I can capture the response text from the request.

What I want to know however, is how to trigger the error eventlistener type?
If I don't want to echo back, say, search results, but alert that there are no results, I want to trigger the 'errorLoading' function.

(no jQuery please)
Thanks guys!

Comment: Have you tried sending a 500 error from your PHP script? `header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error');`

Answer (score 0):

Return either a status code other than 200 (such as 400) or an object that represents error from the server, then call the error handler function.

```
function formatResults(response){

   if(response.error){
       this.errorLoading({error: response.error});
       return;
   }

   if(response.status != 200){
       this.errorLoading({status: response.status});
       return;
   }

   //else no error and continue executing code below this line

}
```